# How to assign a new lambda expression to a function object?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constants

A lambda expression has been defined and assigned/binded to a function object. Now I'd like to assign a new function to that function object. But this assignment casuses compile error in some cases.

I understand that the error comes from the `auto` keyword automatically adding `const` to the function object. Is there anyway to use `auto` together with other key words to remove the `const` binding? I don't really believe `mutable` can serve the purpose as in my code.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984453/passing-lambda-declared-using-auto-keyword-by-non-const-reference-as-argument-to) post explains why without a solution.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639087/how-can-i-overload-operator-for-lambda-assignments) post proposes a solution using a struct, but I wonder if there is a more *elegant* way to do it.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <random>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

void f1();

int main() {
  srand(0);
  f1(); 
  return 0;
}

void f1() {
  using my_pair = pair<int,int>;
  int ref = 2;
  function<bool(const my_pair &,const my_pair &)> comp_1 = [&ref](const my_pair &LHS, const my_pair &RHS) {return LHS.first-ref > RHS.first-ref;};
  comp_1 = [&ref](const my_pair &LHS, const my_pair &RHS) {return LHS.first < RHS.first;};
  // So far so good.
  auto comp_2 = [&ref](const my_pair &LHS, const my_pair &RHS) mutable {return LHS.first-ref > RHS.first-ref;};
    // Compile error below!
  comp_2 = [&ref](const my_pair &LHS, const my_pair &RHS) mutable {return LHS.first < RHS.first;};
    // Compile error above

    // Applications of the function object
  priority_queue<my_pair, vector<my_pair>, decltype(comp_2)> myHeap(comp_2);
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) myHeap.emplace(rand()%10,rand()%20);
  while (!myHeap.empty()) {
    printf("<%d,%d>\n",myHeap.top().first,myHeap.top().second);
    myHeap.pop();
  }

}
```

Comment: The exact error message would be a useful thing to have.

Comment: *"I understand that the error comes from the auto keyword automatically adding const"* what? The problem here is that `auto` is deduced as the lambda type, not `std::function`, and each lambda has its own type, so you cannot assign a new lambda to the previous one.

Comment: `comp_2` type is the type of the lambda given to initialize it... The 2 lambdas have 2 distinct types.

Comment: You can use `using MyFunc_t = function<bool(const my_pair &,const my_pair &)>;` or `typedef` to get a shorter name and use it instead of `auto comp_2 = ...` - `MyFunc_t comp_2 = ...`.

Comment: You *could* pass the different implementations [through a lambda to unify the types](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73c480dc3cc561c8). I'd not recommend doing so however--the error quality reduces significantly given you're calling the variadic lambda result of passing a lambda into a generic lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Each lambda expression is a literal of a anonymous type; two different lambdas, even of the same prototype and the same capture list, are objects of two distinct types. Moreover, [this type's assignment operator is deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), so you could not even possibly assign it to itself:

```
$ cat omg.cpp
int main() {
    auto f = []{};
    f = f;
}
$ g++ omg.cpp
omg.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
omg.cpp:3:4: error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda()>& main()::<lambda()>::operator=(const main()::<lambda()>&)’
  f = f;
    ^
omg.cpp:2:12: note: a lambda closure type has a deleted copy assignment operator
```